# How do I do if on curl in shell script?

Tags: shell, if-statement, curl, sed

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME=$1

#curl -s https://instagram.com/$NAME/ | grep image | grep fbma | sed 's,s150x150/,,g' | cut -f 4 -d '"'

if [ s150x150 ]

then

curl -s https://instagram.com/$NAME/ | grep "og:image" | sed 's,s150x150/,s960x960,g' | sed 's,vp/,,g' | cut -f 4 -d '"'

else

curl -s https://instagram.com/$NAME/ | grep "og:image" | cut -f 4 -d '"'

fi
```

So as you see I have a shell script, and if my output contains "s150x150" I want it to sed vp/, but else I want it to dont do that. Problem is that it does always the if even though it doesn't contain "s150x150". How do I solve this?

Comment: `if [ s150x150 ]` checks if the string `s150x150` is non-empty. It's *always* non-empty, because `"s150x150"` is not `""`. Nothing in your code compares output against... well... *anything*, and it's not clear how it could be expected to do so.

Comment: Using uppercase identifiers like `NAME` for user variables is a bad idea. You may well override an environment variable in the process..

Comment: @CharlesDuffy im not very experienced on this as you may see, do you how i can solve it?

Answer (score 1):

```
# Use lowercase identifiers for user variables.

name=$1
# Store the curl result in a variable
# This helps you avoid multiple curl commands
var=$(curl -s "https://www.instagram.com/${name}/")
# Note above that url is double quoted so that $name will not undergo word-splitting
if [[ "$var" =~ s150x150 ]] # Match variable against pattern
then
   # use herestrings '<<<' to feed $var to sed
   # sed grep combinations can be replaced with a single sed
   # You could concatenate multiple sed commands using ';'
   sed -n '/og:image/{s#s150x150/#s960x960#g;s#vp/##g;p}' <<<"$var" | cut -f 4 -d '"'
else
   sed -n '/og:image/p' <<<"$var" | cut -f 4 -d '"'
fi
```

---

<sup>More about herestrings [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html#AEN17837). Also, this script has been verified by [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) as confirming to best practices.</sup>